# How to remove orphan character from bibliography

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, hyphenation, microtype

Compile with pdflatex 1.14.16 (Miktex) the following source:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biolinum}
\usepackage{XCharter}       
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\isopage[12]
\addbibresource{bug.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Using the the following `bug.bib` (slightly edited from the real one):

```
@Article{Zwaan2004,
  Title                    = {Moving words: Dynamic representations in language comprehension},
  Author                   = {Zwaan, Rolf A. and Madden, Carol J. and Yaxley, Richard H. and Aveyard, Mark E.},
  Date                     = {2004},
  Journaltitle             = {Cognitive Science Xxx Xxx Xxx Xxx},
  Doi                      = {10.1207/s15516709cog2804_5},
  Number                   = {4},
  Pages                    = {611--619},
  Volume                   = {28}
}
```

The result is awful especially because this is the last entry of my bibliography:
[image: The result]

The rest of the paper and the bibliography is correctly formatted, except this last entry. I experimented with various `microtype` option, but nothing helps.

The only way to not have the 5 alone on the last line is to change the `_` with another letter like `W`. But this is not a suitable solution.

My question: how to force not to hyphenate after the `_` or how to force the line to compress the spaces better. Thanks!

Comment: Why all the `Xxx` after Cognitive Science? Isn't the journal called just *Cognitive Science*?

Comment: Choose to list all authors, and everything will be fine. There's a kind of disrespect to omit some of them I believe.

Comment: To create a MWE I removed few formatting things from the entry i.e. vol. and num. so added Xxx to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Re all authors. Could be a solution, as is adding a note. But it is not the point here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reset the url-Breaks in the bib-entry with the execute key:

```
@Article{Zwaan2004,
  Title                    = {Moving words: Dynamic representations in language comprehension},
  Author                   = {Zwaan, Rolf A. and Madden, Carol J. and Yaxley, Richard H. and Aveyard, Mark E.},
  Date                     = {2004},
  Journaltitle             = {Cognitive Science Xxx Xxx Xxx Xxx},
  Doi                      = {10.1207/s15516709cog2804_5},
  Number                   = {4},
  Pages                    = {611--619},
  Volume                   = {28},
  execute= {\def\UrlBreaks{}}
}
```

[image]